# Fetch https enabled url in bing search api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bing

I'm using the api https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?search_term to connect to the Bing Search API and find the desired image/video based on serach term. This works very good, but I'd like Bing to return only https urls. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide some queries where you are getting http sites?